# Limiting Parallel/Simultaneous Downloads - How to know if download was cancelled?

Tags: php, mysql, download

I have a simple file upload service, written out in PHP, which also includes a script that controls download speeds by sending limited-sized packets when a user requests a download from this site.

I want to implement a system to limit parallel/simultaneous downloads to 1 per user if they are not premium members. In the download script above, I can use a MySQL database to store a record that has: (1) the user ID; (2) the file ID; (3) when the download was initiated; and (4) when the last packet was sent, which is updated each time this is done (if DL speed is limited to 150 kB/sec, then after every 150 kB, this record is updated, etc.).

However, thus far, the database record will only be deleted once the download has successfully completed — at the end of the script, after the download has been fully served, the record is deleted from the table:

```
insert DB record;
while (download is being served) {
    serve packet of data;
    update DB record with current date/time;
}
// Download is now complete
delete DB record;
```

How will I be able to detect when a download has been cancelled? Would I just have to have a Cron job (or something similar) detect if an existing download record is more than X minutes/hours old? Or is there something else I can do that I'm missing?

I hope I've explained this well enough. I don't think posting specific code is required; I'm interested more in the logistics of how/whether this can be done. If specific is needed, I will gladly provide it.

NOTE: I know how to detect if a file was successfully downloaded; I need to know how to detect if it was cancelled, aborted, or otherwise stopped (and not just paused). **This will be useful in stopping parallel downloads, as well as preventing a situation where the user cancels Download #1 and tries to initiate Download #2, only to find that the site claims he is still downloading file #1.**

EDIT: You can find my download script here: http://codetidy.com/1319/ — it already supports multi-part downloads and download resuming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php

class DownloadObserver
{
  protected $file;
  public function __construct($file) {
    $this->file = $file;
  }

  public function send() {
    // -> note in DB you've started
    readfile($this->file);
  }

  public function __destruct() {
    // download is done, either completed or aborted
    $aborted = connection_aborted();
    // -> note in DB
  }
}

$dl = new DownloadObserver("/tmp/whatever");
$dl->send();
```

should work just fine. No need for a shutdown_function or any funky self-built connection observation.

Comment: I'm assuming the `public function send()` will also contain the script to limit download size, handle resumed downloads, etc.? In the `__destruct()` function, I could then compare the `$bytes_sent` and `$bytes_total` to see if it was aborted/cancelled vs. successfully complete, right? This looks much cleaner.

Comment: You're assuming right. As you already had your other issues sorted out, I merely point out the object oriented approach (specifically __destruct()) to solve your "catching the end of things" problem.

Comment: I believe this is the best direction I should take. It's object-oriented, neatly contained, and easy to read. I'm trying to go with as much OO code as possible these days, so this is the best answer. Thanks to all!

Comment: Here's some stuff I pulled out of my WebDAV implementation: https://gist.github.com/1307754 (no, I did not test the code, and I haven't used it in ages. It might give you some more hints, through)

Answer (score 1):

You will want to check out the following functions: connection_status(), connection_aborted() and ignore_user_abort() (see the [connection handling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php) section of the PHP manual for more info).

Although I can't guarantee the reliability (it's been a while since I've played around with it), with the right combination you should be able to accomplish what you want. There are a few caveats when working with these though, the big one being that if something goes wrong you could end up with stranded PHP scripts running on the server requiring you to kill Apache to stop them.

The following should give you a good idea of how to do it (adapted from the PHP code examples and a couple of the comments):

```
<?php
//Set PHP not to cancel execution if the connection is aborted
//and drop the time limit to allow for big file downloads
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);

while(true){
    //See the ignore_user_abort() docs re having to send data
    echo chr(0);

    //Make sure the data gets flushed properly or the connection check won't work
    flush();
    ob_flush();

    //Check then connection status and exit loop if aborted
    if(connection_status() != CONNECTION_NORMAL || connection_aborted()) break;

    //Just to provide some spacing in this example
    sleep(1);
}

file_put_contents("abort.txt", "aborted\n", FILE_APPEND);

//Never hurts to ensure that the script halts execution
die();
```

Obviously for how you would be using it the data being sent would simply be the download data chunk (just make sure you flush the buffer properly to ensure the data is actually sent). As far as I'm aware, there is no way of making a distinction between pausing and aborting/stopping. Pause/resume functionality (and multi-part downloading - i.e. how download managers accelerate downloads) relies on the "Range" header, basically requesting byte x to byte y of the file. So if you want to allow resumable downloads you'll have to deal with that too.

Comment: Would `register_shutdown_function` be useful in this at all? In my current code, I have a commented-out section that I must have copied from the site I got the code from, which says to use it to run a particular function upon aborting/finish the download. You can find my download script here: http://codetidy.com/1319/ (it is passed an "ID" GET parameter)

Comment: I guess what I could do is have two global PHP variables in this script that store (1) how many bytes have been served so far, and (2) how many bytes total the file is. In the shutdown function, if the bytes_served < bytes_total, then the file was aborted. Otherwise, it was completed successfully. The thing is, will be shutdown function be called when the page itself is closed, or when the download itself is stopped? Technically, `dl.php` is still running while the download is being served to the user, even if the page itself is not open in a tab.

Comment: die() and exit *can* hurt. For example when PHP is running in fcgid - every exit kills the otherwise cacheable process. wasting performance and filling logs.

Comment: There is a `die()` function at the end of my `download_file` function. I'm assuming this will call the `register_shutdown_function()` function. I already have support for resuming downloads, where the # of bytes sent and # of bytes total are both tracked. I'm assuming I can then simply register a shutdown function which checks these two values, right?

Comment: Doing it this way gives you better control over knowing when the connection has been aborted and as such when you can stop serving the file. That, plus you will be able to handle the aborted process right there and then instead of having to try and catch it with __destructs or shutdown functions. Would the script you posted not work exactly as is if after the while loop you simply added `if(connection_aborted()){//do cleanup}`?

Comment: I don't know. Would it? If so, I'd rather just keep my own code intact and simply add `if (connection_aborted) ...` after the while loop. Is this substantially better than declaring a shutdown function?

Answer (score 0):

There is no HTTP "cancel" signal that is sent by default. So, it looks like you will need to decide on a timeout, the length of time a connection can sit without sending/receiving another packet. If you are sending rather small packets (as I presume you are) keep the timeout short for best effect.

In your while condition you will need to check the age of the last timestamp update, if its too old, stop sending the file.

Comment: Hmm, I would also have to check to see if the record still exists (i.e. it wasn't yet deleted by the cron job that checks for expired download records). If it's not there, end the download (and the script), because it was deemed expired. Does that sound about right?