# PHP How to limit parallel downloads?

Tags: php, file, download, parallel-processing

I am currently developing a web application in which the user can download some files. However, I would like to limit the number of simultaneous downloads for the user. For example, if the user is currently downloading a file A, he can't download another file until his download has been finished or he canceled his download.

I would like to be able to know when a download finished or when a user abort a download. I tried to implement this kind of "algorithm" ([Limiting Parallel/Simultaneous Downloads - How to know if download was cancelled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864407/php-limiting-parallel-simultaneous-downloads-how-to-know-if-download-was-canc)) but it seems not work. The script doesn't run on the destructor apparently.

So if you have any solution, I listen to you.

Thank you.

Comment: The algorithm that you linked to looks like it should work. What version of PHP are you running (destructors were introduced in PHP5)? Note also that destructors are not called until the variable that holds an instance of the class is not needed anymore (see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php ). Also, if you post your code for the implementation of the algorithm, it might be easier to help.

Comment: Could you please provide a code sample and confirm you are using PHP 5+ in order for us to help you debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this from your web server. If using apache try mod_limitipconn.c or for nginx try HttpLimitConnModule

- apache 1.x: http://dominia.org/djao/limitipconn.html
- apache 2.x: http://dominia.org/djao/limitipconn2.html
- nginx 1.2.6: Use [HttpLimitConnModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLimitConnModule)